# GraphPlot3D different colours of edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color, rendering

How can I plot edges with different colours in a GraphPlot3D? 
Porperties of edges are collected in a vector, I want to plot each edges in a range of colours consistent to these properties.

```
    q = {1, -1, 1};
Graph1 = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
3 \[DirectedEdge] 4}, EdgeWeight -> q];
ew = PropertyValue[Graph1, EdgeWeight];
el = EdgeList[Graph1];
edgestylea = 
Thread[el -> (Directive[CapForm["Round"], 
    Thickness[Rescale[#, Through@{Min, Max}@ew, {0.02, .06}]], 
    ColorData[1, #]] & /@ ew)];
GraphPlot3D[Graph1, VertexLabeling -> True, 
EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeStyle -> edgestylea , 
 Cylinder[#1, .5]} &), 
VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Yellow, Sphere[#, 1]} &), 
VertexCoordinateRules -> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 
10, 0}} , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style[Framed["Grafo"], 20, White, Background -> Lighter[Blue]]]
```

---

My code...

```
q = {100, 40, -10};
Graph1 = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
3 \[DirectedEdge] 4}, EdgeWeight -> q];
ew = PropertyValue[Graph1, EdgeWeight];
el = EdgeList[Graph1];
edgestylea = 
Thread[el -> (Directive[CapForm["Round"], 
    Thickness[Rescale[#, Through@{Min, Max}@ew, {0.02, .06}]], 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][#]] & /@ ew)];
Legended[Graph3D[el, EdgeStyle -> edgestylea, EdgeWeight -> q, 
EdgeShapeFunction -> (Cylinder[#1, .5] &), 
VertexShapeFunction -> ({Yellow, Sphere[#, 1]} &), 
VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 10, 
 0}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style[Framed["Grafo"], 20, White, Background -> Lighter[Blue]]], 
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {Min[q], Max[q]}}]]
```

It doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Graph3D.

```
el = {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 4};
edgestylea = 
  Thread[el -> (Directive[CapForm["Round"], 
        Thickness[Rescale[#, Through@{Min, Max}@ew, {0.02, .06}]], 
        ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#]] & /@ ew)];

Graph3D[el, EdgeStyle -> edgestylea, EdgeWeight -> q, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (Cylinder[#1, .5] &), 
 VertexShapeFunction -> ({Yellow, Sphere[#, 1]} &), 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {10, 0, 10}, {10, 10, 
    0}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Framed["Grafo"], 20, White, Background -> Lighter[Blue]]]
```

I changed ColorData[1,#] to ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] due to -1 value.

Comment: I want to plot my graph with the legend too. Can you help me?

Comment: you could use Legended:  Legended[graph, 
 SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}]]

Comment: I would like to use a barlegend with min=Min[q] and max=Max[q]. How can I do it?